# CSS - Help me style this menu without using margins?

Tags: html, css, html-lists, margin

I'm creating a site where I've encountered a huge IE lag when hovering over the menus. 
I'm using Cufon in combination and it seems like it's causing a huge lag when I apply height, width, margins or paddings to the li:hover element.

So, I need to figure out a smart way of doing this otherwise. 
The site is here, http://w3box.com/mat

You can clearly see the menu I guess. 
So, what I want is to push the entire menu downwards so it's like 3 or 4 pixels above the bottom of the height line. So it matches about the same vertical position as the logo font to the left.

Then, I want the hover effect to be larger in height. Hard to explain, but when hovering over a menu item, imagine a box where the text is positioned at the very bottom of the box. Like this;

http://img710.imageshack.us/img710/2791/menuheader.jpg

Now, you may notice the arrow looking thingy sticking at the bottom. I don't really need that, but if you have any idea on how to do it, I'd appreciate the help! ;)

Comment: You will better off asking this question on doctype.com.

Comment: Wow, thanx! Didn't know about doctype.com. Looks promising! :)

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried, but I think this may be an option.

You have everything with in one div, why dont you try to put div with in divs?

this is your current code for header.

```
<div id="header">  
                <img class="LogoChef" src="img/LogoKokk2.png" alt="Logo"/> 

                <img class="LogoMatkalender" src="img/MatkalenderLogo.png" alt="Logo"/>                     


                    <ul class="menuwrapper"> 
                        <li><h4><a href="#">Logg ut</a></h4></li> 
                        <li><h4><a href="#">Kontakt</a></h4></li> 
                        <li><h4><a href="#">Kontrollpanel</a></h4></li> 
                    <li><h4><a href="#">Oppskrifter</a></h4></li> 
                    <li><h4><a href="#">Hjem</a></h4></li> 
                    </ul> 



            </div>
```

You can try something like this, so you have more control over the different objects.

```
<div id="header" style="float:left;vertical-align:bottom">  
<div id="imgChef">
    <img class="LogoChef" src="img/LogoKokk2.png" alt="Logo"/> 
</div>
<div id="imgMat" style="float:left;vertical-align:bottom">
    <img class="LogoMatkalender" src="img/MatkalenderLogo.png" alt="Logo"/>                     
 </div
 <div id="menu" style="float:right;vertical-align:bottom">
<ul class="menuwrapper"> 
<li><h4><a href="#">Logg ut</a></h4></li>                                                              <li><h4><a href="#">Kontakt</a></h4></li> 
<li><h4><a href="#">Kontrollpanel</a></h4></li> 
<li><h4><a href="#">Oppskrifter</a></h4></li> 
<li><h4><a href="#">Hjem</a></h4></li> 
</ul> 
 </div>


</div>
```

I am not sure that may be the right combination, but I think with the three divs inside the div you will gain more control over the elements inside the header div.

Comment: Ah, that sounds kinda logical :) Without too much hassle either.
I might create a class for them though, if they have identical properties. I'll try this in a bit :)

Any idea on how to get that downwards arrow? Don't know if it's possible, since that would require three divs or something, inside one <li> element. Where the middle one is centered. Which is probably impossible?

Comment: The first think is that you may want to apply the hover effect to the "a" element insted the "li" element so...
.menuwrapper a:hover {
 background-image: url(img/MenuHover.png);
}
instead of
.menuwrapper li:hover {
 background-image: url(img/MenuHover.png);
}
Then I think what you need is 
.menuwrapper a:active {background-image: url(img/MenuHoverWithArrowInTheMiddle.png)}  /* selected link */
of course you will need to create that new image.
This will put the image with the arrow when user select the link.

Answer (score 0):

Omit the h4 in the menu since i think it is not needed. Than set `display:block` on `<a>` and use `line-height` and `padding-left , padding-right` to make the anchor expand the right size. Also notice that li:hover is not supported in IE6/7 without some tweaks. To position the menu on same level as logo just set a `margin-top` on ul element.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't use the <h4> at first, I just tried it out since I saw on an example of Cufon that it was done, because Cufon and IE has trouble with <ul> or something. Don't know, will probably throw it out. Ok, I'll try out your tips here :) I'll come back to you.

Answer (score 0):

There're too many rules for me, too many useless rules.
Don't have the time to correct all and test it on FF/IE, but this works ofr example :
.menuwrapper li {
   float:right;
   list-style: none;
   padding: 30px 23px 3px 23px;
   position: relative;
   top: 7px;
}

Answer (score 0):

What about **vertical-align**?